# Google Maps integration kills jquery animations (in Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, maps

I'm currently working on my personal photography portfolio which is going to look like this:

[Screenshot](http://cl.ly/7xvB)

According to the maps integration I've decided to implement the Google Maps Map via Javascript in order to make all the "hotspots" clickable and fire off javascript functions. (change the description and the thumbnail image)

The animation when clicking on a google maps marker works fine in Firefox, but when I try it out in Safari the animation doesn't seem to work.
I've uploaded this page to the following Url: [Photogen Worldmap](http://janiklipke.com/photogen_map/worldmap.html)

Maybe it's just a simple bug or whatever, Anybody got an idea?
Cheers, Janik

Comment: I tried out several tricks but wasn't able to fix this.
Anyway: As soon as I drag the map, the animation finishes, so this really seems to be tough error.
I also tested the web page on two other macs running the latest safari, they both have the same error, so it's not a local problem.

Answer (score 0):

Animates fine on Safari 5.05 on my Win7 machine. Try disabling any plugins you might have running on Safari. Is this on PC or Mac?

Comment: This is probably better as a comment on the original question, not an answer.

Comment: I'm running Safari on a Mac with no additional Plugins installed.